# VS Code code formatting JavaScript incorrectly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide

As above, and presented in the screenshot.

Using *Format document* on valid JS code (no space between question marks) produces errors.

What I've tried so far was to change formatter, but to no avail.
Error is especially irritating because I have formatting on save option on and I like it that way. Studio version is 1.46.

If you want to reproduce it yourself, feel free:

```
let iForgotToInitializeThat = undefined;
const coalesceResult = iForgotToInitializeThat ?? 'something';
```

And try to format it.
[image: Code making curious decision]

Comment: Everything working.

Comment: what's the ?? for

Comment: Install ```Nullish Coalescing Operator Grammar```

Comment: @WilliamKun https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried your code and it works properly in my case, but have [prettier formatter extension](https://prettier.io/) configured to format my code, maybe you can try it.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Upon further investigation, it actually was problem with formatter - Beautify doesn't like null coalescing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Beautify then it will indicate an error. Try to use Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a formatter was installed along side prettier, which was deprecated and causing spaces. Its always good idea to disable extensions one by one and see which is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed Beautify that is a deprecated extension.
and then that problem was fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).